# Text on Webpage is visible

Tags: robotframework

I am trying to make sure I have Element Text visible before I move onto the next step on my test. This is what I have tried:
Element Text Should Be      `//<span class="quote__summary__level">public liability only</span> Public Liability Only` because the text I want to make sure are visible on the page is Public Liability Only

I have also triend `<span class="quote__summary__level">public liability only</span>    Public Liability Only`

But I am getting this error: `InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //<span class="quote__summary__level">public liability only</span> because of the following error: SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//<span class="quote__summary__level">public liability only</span>' is not a valid XPath expression.`

What am I doing wrong please?

This is the element of the text on the website: `<span class="quote__summary__level">public liability only</span>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Element Text Should Be    xpath://span[@class="quote__summary__level"]    public liability only
```

your locator is incorrect read how to locate element https://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/Selenium2Library.html#Locating%20elements

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Really appreciate it,